# Storing metadata and raw data separately

Tags: oracle, mongodb, couchbase, database

Is there an advantage to storing the metadata (or indexing data) for a document/*LOB separate from the raw data.

For instance having a table/collection/bucket with index on (name,school)

```
ID: 123
name: Johny
School: Harvard
Transcript: /*2MB text/binary*/
```

**vs**

Metadata

```
ID: 123
name: Johny
School: Harvard
```

Data

```
ID: 123
Transcripts: /*2MB text/binary*/
```

Let's assume mongodb, although it's really db agnostic perhaps.

```
db.firstModel.find({},{transcripts:0})
```

vs

```
db.secondModel.find()
```

Additionally if we have aggregation/grouping on the metadata, would the heavy payload in transcripts weigh it down (even though the aggregation is on other fields)? is it better to aggregate on the metadata collection separately, then retrieve by id from the data collection? Or is it better to respect the database design (keeping everything coupled in a single document)?

Comment: Yes it can be used for search fast; keywords/tags can be saved in separate column and this column can be used in search queries.

Comment: not to mention how scattered table will come with EACH update on short column... eg you change the student name to fix misspell and you actually move 2MB of data (to change 2 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

In Couchbase, if it works for your use case, an option might be to have the object ID for your 2MB document something like **harvard::johny::123**. Every object would have such a pattern for each object ID that is used consistently in your application. Therefore your application easily piece together the object ID. Then you do not have to query or use views. You know it is harvard and johny and his 123rd object, you can just get it by ID. You already know the answer, no querying and so Couchbase will be very fast.

That being said, there may be other meta data that you want to keep in that metadata object and you want to index on and then yes, in Couchbase it might be better to break out the documents like you suggest. In Couchbase it might even be better to put them in separate buckets so the indexers are only looking at things it will index.

For an example that may not be entirely applicable to your use case, but should give you an idea of what is possible [go here](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/july/advanced-object-modeling-for-high-write-rates-with-logging-and-event-data)

All of that being said, from experience I do not like keeping larger object like you suggest in a DB long term, regardless of the DB. From an operational perspective it is terrible. You are storing what amounts to static data in a layer that needs to be very performant, with usually expensive storage and having to backup those objects over time. They become a boat anchor around your neck after a few months/years. I suggest keeping the meta-data in a fast performing system like Couchbase (cache+persistence with replication, etc) that also has a pointer to the large objects in something that is best for dishing out large static objects like HDFS, Amazon S3, etc.

Comment: Oh and for MongoDB splitting the docs up may or may not buy you much. It will depend on how you plan to read and write the data. If you update the larger object with a 1 character JSON change and it no longer fits into its slot, Mongo will have to pick it up and migrate it. In that case, splitting them up would be a good thing. If it is a write once and just read, then it might make sense to just leave them in the same document. I still do not recommend storing the large object in Mongo either for the same reasons I stated. Just because you can, does not mean you should.